# Angular 4 Firebase angularfire Sorting a list by value

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I am using Angular 4 Firebase and AngularFire and i have the following firebase database

```
"users" : {
    "Test1" : {
      "totalscore" : 50,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test2" : {
      "totalscore" : 30,
      "username" : "test2"
    },
    "Test3" : {
      "totalscore" : 20,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test4" : {
      "totalscore" : 10,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test5" : {
      "totalscore" : 50,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test6" : {
      "totalscore" : 30,
      "username" : "test2"
    },
    "Test7" : {
      "totalscore" : 20,
      "username" : "test1"
    },
    "Test8" : {
      "totalscore" : 10,
      "username" : "test1"
    }
  }
```

I read the documents of firebase and AngularFire and I want to get those data
as a sorted list by totalscore.I tried all the possible ways given by this [AngularFire link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md) but nothing helped.I currently got this code which works fine but it doesnt sort the list.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homefiller',
  templateUrl: './homefiller.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homefiller.component.css']
})

export class HomefillerComponent implements OnInit {
  topusers: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  totalscore;
  list;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {


        this.topusers = db.list('users', {
        query: {
         orderByValue: true,
         limitToFirst: 10,
        }
        });
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Can you help me with a way to sort my list by

> "totalscore:"

or tell me if it is possible to do that??
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderByValue` is used when you have a data structure like this:

```
"userscores" : {
    "Test1" : 50,
    "Test2" : 30,
    "Test3" : 20
    "Test4" : 10,
}
```

In the above you want to order the results of your query on `userscores` on the value of each child node.

In your case, the value you want to sort on is in a child property `totalscore` under `users`. So you should use orderByChild:

```
this.topusers = db.list('users', {
    query: {
     orderByChild: "totalscore",
     limitToFirst: 10,
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you very much this worked!! It gets the list from the smaller to the bigger and I prefer the opossite is there any way to invert it??

Comment: Firebase always returns the items in ascending order. Two options are to: 1) reverse the result client side, 2) store an inverted value for querying. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185647/sort-data-descending-list-firebase-angular2) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order/25613337#25613337) respectively.